# Sort Function Excel Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vb.net, function, sorting

I am trying to do a Excel Function with order data with Visual Basic

```
Function DobleMax(rgn As range)

DobleMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sort(rgn)    

End Function
```

The function does not work, return the same array.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you post a small example of `rgn` for which your function leaves it unsorted?

Answer (score 0):

As a comment:
This works fine using Office 365 using the above-mentioned function

[image]